# Javascript Countdown & IE

Tags: javascript

Added:

Ok to add some additional details as I thought you had to keep the questions concise
but it has been downvoted for lack of research. This script was about the third or fourth
that I had tried to do what I wanted and work across the various browsers. When it did
not work I did search for resources to help and thought it may be the way the countdown is output in that IE doesn't like the Input ID so tried other ways to display it but couldn't get it to work hence the question. There is no error displayed one IE it just doesn't show anything - hence it is just a guess about the input id.

I found this Javascript code - maybe even off here and it does exactly what I want
and shows up fine in FF & Chrome. Unfortunately though it doesn't show the countdown
at all in IE and wondered if there is any way of changing the way the countdown is
output that would be compatible with IE.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 5;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
}
function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>
```

And displaying it like this:

```
<div id="timer">
Time Ending In: <input id="minutes" type="text"> minutes and <input id="seconds"         type="text"> seconds.
</div>
   <script>
   countdown();
   </script>
```

As I say the above displays fine in FF & Chrome - is there any way to get it to work in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: Sorry - Have I done something wrong??

Comment: Well you're passing strings to `setTimeout` and expecting JavaScript to be realtime (even though it's not - almost, but not quite). You're also throwing a global variable all over the place, rather than using parameters or scopes... It doesn't look like you've even tried to get a basic understanding of the code you're using.

Comment: I wanted a timedown counter - found the code in reply to an answer on here and assumed (my bad) that it would work - it does - just not in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var minutes, seconds;

// set minutes
var mins = 5;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;

function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);

}
function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>
<div id="timer">
Time Ending In: <input id="minutes" type="text"> minutes and <input id="seconds" type="text"> seconds.
</div>
   <script>
   countdown();
   </script>
```

Comment: Many thanks aliveli for your assistance - appreciated - all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript">...`
`var minutes, seconds;`
`...`